# Converting accented characters and HTML entities into UTF-8?

Tags: php, html, encoding, utf-8, html-entities

I'm working on a project that will allow me to download stories from Portkey.org for reading on my kindle, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to properly encode/parse the grabbed HTML from the website. I am using [simple_html_dom](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/) to grab it, and am passing the `innertext` of the main element where the story is held for parsing.

So what I'm trying to accomplish here is the following:

1. Grab HTML from Portkey.org story
2. Convert all HTML Entities on page to regular characters for reading (entities like `&rdquo;` to `”`, `&ldquo;` to `“`, `&hellip;` to `…` and so on)
3. Any accented characters or characters of other languages (like Korean, Japanese, Chinese, etc.) should stay as they are.
4. Fix the HTML using `tidy` and save it to a `.html` file.

Everything I have tried so far results in either of the following:

- Diamond with question mark inside of it where the accented characters should be
- Broken UTF-8 characters where there should be quotations and ellipses, but accented characters show correctly

A sample from the story HTML:

```
<p> Wel [snip] your emotions&hellip;but most impor [snip] ng fiancé </p>
```

**EDIT**

`html_entity_decode` results in the following output:

```
 Wel [snip] your emotionsâ€¦but most impor [snip] ng fiancé
```

As you can see, the accented character is correct, but the `&hellip;` now displays incorrectly.

**EDIT 2:**

Results of `get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES)`:

```
array(252) { ["""]=> string(6) """ ["&"]=> string(5) "&" ["<"]=> string(4) "<" [">"]=> string(4) ">" ["Â "]=> string(6) " " ["Â¡"]=> string(7) "¡" ["Â¢"]=> string(6) "¢" ["Â£"]=> string(7) "£" ["Â¤"]=> string(8) "¤" ["Â¥"]=> string(5) "¥" ["Â¦"]=> string(8) "¦" ["Â§"]=> string(6) "§" ["Â¨"]=> string(5) "¨" ["Â©"]=> string(6) "©" ["Âª"]=> string(6) "ª" ["Â«"]=> string(7) "«" ["Â¬"]=> string(5) "¬" ["Â­"]=> string(5) "­" ["Â®"]=> string(5) "®" ["Â¯"]=> string(6) "¯" ["Â°"]=> string(5) "°" ["Â±"]=> string(8) "±" ["Â²"]=> string(6) "²" ["Â³"]=> string(6) "³" ["Â´"]=> string(7) "´" ["Âµ"]=> string(7) "µ" ["Â¶"]=> string(6) "¶" ["Â·"]=> string(8) "·" ["Â¸"]=> string(7) "¸" ["Â¹"]=> string(6) "¹" ["Âº"]=> string(6) "º" ["Â»"]=> string(7) "»" ["Â¼"]=> string(8) "¼" ["Â½"]=> string(8) "½" ["Â¾"]=> string(8) "¾" ["Â¿"]=> string(8) "¿" ["Ã€"]=> string(8) "À" ["Ã"]=> string(8) "Á" ["Ã‚"]=> string(7) "Â" ["Ãƒ"]=> string(8) "Ã" ["Ã„"]=> string(6) "Ä" ["Ã…"]=> string(7) "Å" ["Ã†"]=> string(7) "Æ" ["Ã‡"]=> string(8) "Ç" ["Ãˆ"]=> string(8) "È" ["Ã‰"]=> string(8) "É" ["ÃŠ"]=> string(7) "Ê" ["Ã‹"]=> string(6) "Ë" ["ÃŒ"]=> string(8) "Ì" ["Ã"]=> string(8) "Í" ["ÃŽ"]=> string(7) "Î" ["Ã"]=> string(6) "Ï" ["Ã"]=> string(5) "Ð" ["Ã‘"]=> string(8) "Ñ" ["Ã’"]=> string(8) "Ò" ["Ã“"]=> string(8) "Ó" ["Ã”"]=> string(7) "Ô" ["Ã•"]=> string(8) "Õ" ["Ã–"]=> string(6) "Ö" ["Ã—"]=> string(7) "×" ["Ã˜"]=> string(8) "Ø" ["Ã™"]=> string(8) "Ù" ["Ãš"]=> string(8) "Ú" ["Ã›"]=> string(7) "Û" ["Ãœ"]=> string(6) "Ü" ["Ã"]=> string(8) "Ý" ["Ãž"]=> string(7) "Þ" ["ÃŸ"]=> string(7) "ß" ["Ã "]=> string(8) "à" ["Ã¡"]=> string(8) "á" ["Ã¢"]=> string(7) "â" ["Ã£"]=> string(8) "ã" ["Ã¤"]=> string(6) "ä" ["Ã¥"]=> string(7) "å" ["Ã¦"]=> string(7) "æ" ["Ã§"]=> string(8) "ç" ["Ã¨"]=> string(8) "è" ["Ã©"]=> string(8) "é" ["Ãª"]=> string(7) "ê" ["Ã«"]=> string(6) "ë" ["Ã¬"]=> string(8) "ì" ["Ã­"]=> string(8) "í" ["Ã®"]=> string(7) "î" ["Ã¯"]=> string(6) "ï" ["Ã°"]=> string(5) "ð" ["Ã±"]=> string(8) "ñ" ["Ã²"]=> string(8) "ò" ["Ã³"]=> string(8) "ó" ["Ã´"]=> string(7) "ô" ["Ãµ"]=> string(8) "õ" ["Ã¶"]=> string(6) "ö" ["Ã·"]=> string(8) "÷" ["Ã¸"]=> string(8) "ø" ["Ã¹"]=> string(8) "ù" ["Ãº"]=> string(8) "ú" ["Ã»"]=> string(7) "û" ["Ã¼"]=> string(6) "ü" ["Ã½"]=> string(8) "ý" ["Ã¾"]=> string(7) "þ" ["Ã¿"]=> string(6) "ÿ" ["Å’"]=> string(7) "Œ" ["Å“"]=> string(7) "œ" ["Å "]=> string(8) "Š" ["Å¡"]=> string(8) "š" ["Å¸"]=> string(6) "Ÿ" ["Æ’"]=> string(6) "ƒ" ["Ë†"]=> string(6) "ˆ" ["Ëœ"]=> string(7) "˜" ["Î‘"]=> string(7) "Α" ["Î’"]=> string(6) "Β" ["Î“"]=> string(7) "Γ" ["Î”"]=> string(7) "Δ" ["Î•"]=> string(9) "Ε" ["Î–"]=> string(6) "Ζ" ["Î—"]=> string(5) "Η" ["Î˜"]=> string(7) "Θ" ["Î™"]=> string(6) "Ι" ["Îš"]=> string(7) "Κ" ["Î›"]=> string(8) "Λ" ["Îœ"]=> string(4) "Μ" ["Î"]=> string(4) "Ν" ["Îž"]=> string(4) "Ξ" ["ÎŸ"]=> string(9) "Ο" ["Î "]=> string(4) "Π" ["Î¡"]=> string(5) "Ρ" ["Î£"]=> string(7) "Σ" ["Î¤"]=> string(5) "Τ" ["Î¥"]=> string(9) "Υ" ["Î¦"]=> string(5) "Φ" ["Î§"]=> string(5) "Χ" ["Î¨"]=> string(5) "Ψ" ["Î©"]=> string(7) "Ω" ["Î±"]=> string(7) "α" ["Î²"]=> string(6) "β" ["Î³"]=> string(7) "γ" ["Î´"]=> string(7) "δ" ["Îµ"]=> string(9) "ε" ["Î¶"]=> string(6) "ζ" ["Î·"]=> string(5) "η" ["Î¸"]=> string(7) "θ" ["Î¹"]=> string(6) "ι" ["Îº"]=> string(7) "κ" ["Î»"]=> string(8) "λ" ["Î¼"]=> string(4) "μ" ["Î½"]=> string(4) "ν" ["Î¾"]=> string(4) "ξ" ["Î¿"]=> string(9) "ο" ["Ï€"]=> string(4) "π" ["Ï"]=> string(5) "ρ" ["Ï‚"]=> string(8) "ς" ["Ïƒ"]=> string(7) "σ" ["Ï„"]=> string(5) "τ" ["Ï…"]=> string(9) "υ" ["Ï†"]=> string(5) "φ" ["Ï‡"]=> string(5) "χ" ["Ïˆ"]=> string(5) "ψ" ["Ï‰"]=> string(7) "ω" ["Ï‘"]=> string(10) "ϑ" ["Ï’"]=> string(7) "ϒ" ["Ï–"]=> string(5) "ϖ" ["â€‚"]=> string(6) " " ["â€ƒ"]=> string(6) " " ["â€‰"]=> string(8) " " ["â€Œ"]=> string(6) "‌" ["â€"]=> string(5) "‍" ["â€Ž"]=> string(5) "‎" ["â€"]=> string(5) "‏" ["â€“"]=> string(7) "–" ["â€”"]=> string(7) "—" ["â€˜"]=> string(7) "‘" ["â€™"]=> string(7) "’" ["â€š"]=> string(7) "‚" ["â€œ"]=> string(7) "“" ["â€"]=> string(7) "”" ["â€ž"]=> string(7) "„" ["â€ "]=> string(8) "†" ["â€¡"]=> string(8) "‡" ["â€¢"]=> string(6) "•" ["â€¦"]=> string(8) "…" ["â€°"]=> string(8) "‰" ["â€²"]=> string(7) "′" ["â€³"]=> string(7) "″" ["â€¹"]=> string(8) "‹" ["â€º"]=> string(8) "›" ["â€¾"]=> string(7) "‾" ["â„"]=> string(7) "⁄" ["â‚¬"]=> string(6) "€" ["â„‘"]=> string(7) "ℑ" ["â„˜"]=> string(8) "℘" ["â„œ"]=> string(6) "ℜ" ["â„¢"]=> string(7) "™" ["â„µ"]=> string(9) "ℵ" ["â†"]=> string(6) "←" ["â†‘"]=> string(6) "↑" ["â†’"]=> string(6) "→" ["â†“"]=> string(6) "↓" ["â†”"]=> string(6) "↔" ["â†µ"]=> string(7) "↵" ["â‡"]=> string(6) "⇐" ["â‡‘"]=> string(6) "⇑" ["â‡’"]=> string(6) "⇒" ["â‡“"]=> string(6) "⇓" ["â‡”"]=> string(6) "⇔" ["âˆ€"]=> string(8) "∀" ["âˆ‚"]=> string(6) "∂" ["âˆƒ"]=> string(7) "∃" ["âˆ…"]=> string(7) "∅" ["âˆ‡"]=> string(7) "∇" ["âˆˆ"]=> string(6) "∈" ["âˆ‰"]=> string(7) "∉" ["âˆ‹"]=> string(4) "∋" ["âˆ"]=> string(6) "∏" ["âˆ‘"]=> string(5) "∑" ["âˆ’"]=> string(7) "−" ["âˆ—"]=> string(8) "∗" ["âˆš"]=> string(7) "√" ["âˆ"]=> string(6) "∝" ["âˆž"]=> string(7) "∞" ["âˆ "]=> string(5) "∠" ["âˆ§"]=> string(5) "∧" ["âˆ¨"]=> string(4) "∨" ["âˆ©"]=> string(5) "∩" ["âˆª"]=> string(5) "∪" ["âˆ«"]=> string(5) "∫" ["âˆ´"]=> string(8) "∴" ["âˆ¼"]=> string(5) "∼" ["â‰…"]=> string(6) "≅" ["â‰ˆ"]=> string(7) "≈" ["â‰ "]=> string(4) "≠" ["â‰¡"]=> string(7) "≡" ["â‰¤"]=> string(4) "≤" ["â‰¥"]=> string(4) "≥" ["âŠ‚"]=> string(5) "⊂" ["âŠƒ"]=> string(5) "⊃" ["âŠ„"]=> string(6) "⊄" ["âŠ†"]=> string(6) "⊆" ["âŠ‡"]=> string(6) "⊇" ["âŠ•"]=> string(7) "⊕" ["âŠ—"]=> string(8) "⊗" ["âŠ¥"]=> string(6) "⊥" ["â‹…"]=> string(6) "⋅" ["âŒˆ"]=> string(7) "⌈" ["âŒ‰"]=> string(7) "⌉" ["âŒŠ"]=> string(8) "⌊" ["âŒ‹"]=> string(8) "⌋" ["âŒ©"]=> string(6) "⟨" ["âŒª"]=> string(6) "⟩" ["â—Š"]=> string(5) "◊" ["â™ "]=> string(8) "♠" ["â™£"]=> string(7) "♣" ["â™¥"]=> string(8) "♥" ["â™¦"]=> string(7) "♦" }
```

**EDIT 3:**

Just for full disclosure, here is a test file I have set up for the purposes of figuring this out. Currently, all entities display correctly, but accented characters display as `�`.

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

require_once('_RESOURCES/simple_html_dom.php');

$url = 'http://fanfiction.portkey.org/index.php?act=read&storyid=1585&chapterid=&agree=1';

function tidyHTML($html) {
    ob_start();
    $tidy = new tidy;
    $config = array('indent' => true, 'output-xhtml' => false, 'wrap' => 200, 'clean' => false, 'show-body-only' => true);
    $tidy->parseString($html, $config, 'utf8');
    $tidy->cleanRepair();
    $input = $tidy;
    return $input;
}

function filter($html) {
    $html = preg_replace('~>\s+<~', '><', $html);
    $html = preg_replace('/<\/b>\s?<b>/', '', $html);
    $html = preg_replace('/<\/i>\s?<i>/', '', $html);
    $html = str_replace('<br>', '', $html);
    $output = $html;
    return $output;
}

$page_html = file_get_html($url);
$chapter_html = $page_html->find('td[class="story"]', 0);
foreach ($chapter_html->find('center') as $node) { $node->outertext = ''; }

$entities = html_entity_decode($chapter_html->innertext, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

echo tidyHTML(filter($entities));

// var_dump(get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES));

?>
```

Comment: Why would you convert entities to characters? It serves no purpose here, since the entities actually work *safer* in HTML (especially if you don’t know how to declare character encoding). Besides, your example contains no entities. It has “é” as such, and no ellipsis “…” at all.

Comment: I'm converting the entities because I will be outputting the story text in a variety of formats, including plaintext. Also, the examle does contain a `&hellip;` as well as the `é`. I will edit the example down to focus on the problem characters.

Comment: If it is in HTML format, generating plain text from it is a much wider issue than just converting entity references to characters. And it can be handled when plain text is actually generated.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php). From the documentation: "converts all HTML entities in the string to their applicable characters." Depending on your PHP version and setup, you may have to specify the encoding manually. Something like:

```
html_entity_decode($raw_text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Tidy may be re-encoding your entities. I'm not sure how complex your input strings are, but could consider just dropping the HTML tags, using something like [strip_tags](http://php.net/strip_tags), if you don't need the formatting to match exactly.

Comment: That's strange. What version of PHP are you using? You may have to manually set the encoding if you're using an older version. I'm editing my answer to include this.

Comment: I am using v5.5.11. I tried manually setting the encoding as per you edit, and it remained exactly the same. broken ellipses, accented character shows correctly.

Comment: Are you looking at the result of html_entity_decode, or the final output? Tidy may be re-escaping your string. Try echoing the result of html_entity_decode directly. You should be able to rule out a few things this way.

Comment: I am indeed echoing the result of html_entity_decode directly.

Comment: Okay, quick sanity check. Can you look at the result of get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES); and just be sure the entity is even there.

Comment: Updated question with translation table. The accented e is in there.

Comment: Looks like some of your entities are garbled. The correct version of the ellipsis isn't there. If you're viewing the results in a browser, be sure the encoding on the page is correct.

Comment: Okay, I added `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');` to the page. All of the entities are displaying as the correct characters, but now the accented characters are displaying as `�`.

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished what I set out to do by changing the encoding of tidy from

`$tidy->parseString($html, $config, 'utf8');`

to

`$tidy->parseString($html, $config, 'win1252');`

This converted the accented characters to HTML entities. I then used `html_entity_decode` to convert all of the entities into UTF-8 characters.

New test file (works!)

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

require_once('_RESOURCES/simple_html_dom.php');

$url = 'http://fanfiction.portkey.org/index.php?act=read&storyid=1585&chapterid=&agree=1';

function tidyHTML($html) {
    ob_start();
    $tidy = new tidy;
    $config = array('indent' => true, 'output-xhtml' => false, 'wrap' => 200, 'clean' => false, 'show-body-only' => true);
    $tidy->parseString($html, $config, 'win1252');
    $tidy->cleanRepair();
    $input = $tidy;
    return $input;
}

function filter($html) {
    $html = preg_replace('~>\s+<~', '><', $html);
    $html = preg_replace('/<\/b>\s?<b>/', '', $html);
    $html = preg_replace('/<\/i>\s?<i>/', '', $html);
    $html = str_replace('<br>', '', $html);
    $output = $html;
    return $output;
}

$page_html = file_get_html($url);
$chapter_html = $page_html->find('td[class="story"]', 0);
foreach ($chapter_html->find('center') as $node) { $node->outertext = ''; }

echo filter(html_entity_decode(tidyHTML($chapter_html->innertext)));

?>
```

Couldn't have done it without you, Skunkwaffle!